# How to open a file from within a zip directly through the Emacs command-line?

Tags: emacs, zip

I'm aware that Zip files can be opened on Emacs through Dired, then individual files accessed. However, I'd like to do the same thing but from the command line. Does Emacs supports this?

Example of the kind of command I'm looking for:

```
emacs --open-zip foo.zip --open-file README.md
```

---

**Edit:** While the current accepted solution is the canonical right one, it isn't applicable to my use case as I'm using OSX which isn't compatible, and cannot easily install Emacs 27 anyway. I'm now looking for a less canonical but more practical solution (maybe by calling a lisp script at Emacs' startup) - having a wrapper around Emacs is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Emacs 27, there is `tramp-archive.el`. It adds access to files in an archive by a special syntax construct, regarding the zip file as directory. Your example would be

```
emacs path/to/foo.zip/README.md
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Archive-file-names for details. Instead of installing Emacs 27, you could also install recent Tramp 2.4.1, which is said to cooperate with older Emacsen.

Note: this works only on GNU/Linux systems.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for OSX?

Comment: Likely not. You need gvfs, and I don't know its availability under macOS.

Comment: And is there a way to do it programmatically with a less convenient syntax, for example by chaining lisp calls? In which case I could maybe abstract it in an emacs wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have a quick and dirty way to open a specific file within an archive from the old (V22) emacs that comes with OSX.

[in action as gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/Ky5zFSkDcCIJxYeVuV/giphy.gif)

Its not tested, or optimal, just a proof of concept.  The contents of the the file `jea_open_specific_file_in_zip.el` are:

```
(defun jea-open-specific-file-in-zip (outer-archive-file-name inner-file-name)
  (progn
    (find-file outer-archive-file-name)
    (while (not (eobp))
      (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'filename)))
        (if bounds
            (let ((zipped-file-name (buffer-substring-no-properties (car bounds) (cdr bounds))))
              (if (string= zipped-file-name inner-file-name)
                  (archive-extract)))))
      (archive-next-line 1))))
```

here is a crude shell capture:

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ rm ./data/test1.zip 
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ 
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ /usr/bin/emacs --version # old emacs that comes with OSX
GNU Emacs 22.1.1
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ 
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ ll ./data/*.md # some test data
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    17B 30 Jul 19:31 ./data/README1.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    17B 30 Jul 19:32 ./data/README2.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    19B 30 Jul 19:32 ./data/README3.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    18B 30 Jul 19:32 ./data/README4.md
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ 
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ cat ./data/*.md
Hello World One!
Hello World Two!
Hello World Three!
Hello World Four!
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ 
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ zip ./data/test1.zip -9 ./data/README1.md ./data/README2.md ./data/README3.md ./data/README4.md
  adding: data/README1.md (stored 0%)
  adding: data/README2.md (stored 0%)
  adding: data/README3.md (stored 0%)
  adding: data/README4.md (stored 0%)
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ 
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ ll ./data/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  7 jamesanderson  staff   224B 30 Jul 22:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 jamesanderson  staff   160B 30 Jul 21:52 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    17B 30 Jul 19:31 README1.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    17B 30 Jul 19:32 README2.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    19B 30 Jul 19:32 README3.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff    18B 30 Jul 19:32 README4.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jamesanderson  staff   725B 30 Jul 22:09 test1.zip
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ 
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-3:open_zip_file jamesanderson$ /usr/bin/emacs -Q --load ./jea_open_specific_file_in_zip.el --eval "(jea-open-specific-file-in-zip \"./data/test1.zip\" \"data/README3.md\")"
```

of opening the third file.  It just loads the elisp code pasted above from the file `jea_open_specific_file_in_zip.el` and then passes in the outer zip file name and the specific inner compressed file's name to the function:  `(jea-open-specific-file-in-zip "./data/test1.zip" "data/README3.md")` with the required escapes.  The `-Q` arg is just a thing to make it not load the init scripts (just so that I would not accidentally use a lib that is local to my machine)

Comment: It seems to work pretty well! I just have the following warning in the console, do you have an idea what could cause this? `let*: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil`

Comment: Great! @MaëlNison my guess is that your real archive file contains some file names that are messing up the let* (my tests were super simple  rudimentary things).  let* is were you declare/assign the variables in lisp.  So I guess that `bounds` is being set to `nil` and messing up the call to `buffer-substring-no-properties` I will try to find time today to improve it with a check on the bounds before use. Hopefully that will fix it.  But so long as it can open the first, last and some of the middle files in the archive it might be fit for use in the short term.

Comment: I fixed it locally (I believe the loop was continuing past the file being opened), and it works great. Thanks for your help!